# Why does the limit of the p-series converge to a non-zero constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

[image]

Here, the limit of the integral apparently converges to infinity as x goes to infinity. What I don't understand though, is how could it possibly converge to a constant of 5/7?

If you multiply 5/7 by x^-14, the number would just be getting smaller and smaller, as x^-14 = 1/x^14. Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a definite integral like $\int_1^b 10x^{-15}\,dx$?

Comment: I thought that was (-5/7)x^-14? Also is latex built into the textbox?

Comment: No, that is an indefinite integral. I suggest that you review definite integration, and then improper integration, because these basics are needed to make sense of the problem above.  The definite integral needed here evaluates to $(-5/7)b^{-14}-(-5/7)1^{-14}=\dfrac57-\dfrac5{7b^{14}}$.

Comment: OHHHH I see. The limit as 5/7b^14 goes to 0, so the limit is effectively 5/7. Also can I use LaTeX in this? Or is there another way to type with math here?

Comment: Yes, MathJax, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference